# WordPress Custom Post Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am trying to loop through the custom WordPress posts and have an issue like I add the custom field and want to display it in `<li>` using loop. I did it successfully but the data/link/category is repeating and I want it to show only once if the category is the same as:

If I have 2 posts with the data1 category then the link will only show data1 **once** but I have 2 posts with different category then it will show each separately.

**Sample Code:**

```
<ul class="filter filter-top">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
        <?php
          $portfolio_args_custom = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
          );
          $portfolio_posts_custom = new WP_Query($portfolio_args_custom);
          while($portfolio_posts_custom->have_posts()) {
            $portfolio_posts_custom->the_post();

       ?>
         <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Category', true);?>"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Category', true);?></a></li>
          <?php   wp_reset_postdata();
          wp_reset_query();
        }?>
      </ul>
```

The code is working fine but it is repeating the `<li>` item with the same category. Please provide any documentation/helping link/ suggestion.

**Edit:**

This code works as I want but It's not clear for me, please explain if possible.

```
 <ul class="filter filter-top">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
            <?php
               $portfolio_args_custom = array(
                'post_type' => 'portfolio',
              );
              $portfolio_posts_custom = new WP_Query($portfolio_args_custom);
              while($portfolio_posts_custom->have_posts()) {
                $portfolio_posts_custom->the_post();
                $categories = get_the_category();

                foreach ( $categories as $key=>$category ) {
          
        
               
           ?>
             <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Category', true);?>"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Category', true);?></a></li>
              <?php   wp_reset_postdata();
              wp_reset_query();
            }
             } 
             ?>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all why do you call **wp_reset_query()** on each **while** iteration?
Then we simply will create new $cats array and check if new "category" is not already there = then show and add it to the array.

```
  <ul class="filter filter-top">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
    <?php
      $portfolio_args_custom = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
      );
      $cats = [];
      $portfolio_posts_custom = new WP_Query($portfolio_args_custom);
      while($portfolio_posts_custom->have_posts()) {
        $portfolio_posts_custom->the_post();
        $cat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Category', true);
        if (!in_array($cat, $cats)) {
           $cats[] = $cat;
   ?>
     <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo $cat;?>"><?php echo $cat;?></a></li>
      <?php } } wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,can you please check the EDIT and also explain the EDIT code foreach,